# Remove vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have inserted a text from a database using SQL, in a div "col1".

HTML

```
<div id="col1">
    <article class="justify" style="width: 100%; min-height: 400px; overflow: auto; margin-top: 0px;">
        <h1>SENASTE ARTIKELN</h1>
        <h3><?php echo $val['title']; ?></h3>
        <h5><?php echo $val['author'] . ', publicerad ' . $val['pubdate']; ?></h5>
        <p><?php echo $val['content']; ?></p>
    </article>

    <p class="right"><a href="articles.php" class="referlink">- Gå till Artiklar</a></p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#col1 {
    width: 293px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The text appears in one line and that results in a long vertical scroll. How do i remove the scroll and make the text just appear within the "width" and word wrapping..?

Thanks!

Comment: use 
overflow-x: hidden; 
to hide scrolling to your main tag or body tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this in CSS :

`word-wrap: break-word;`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kupendra/8yL7k0pj/)

Comment: Now it works! Thanks!  (im new to this site so i just made this answe "not useful" , but it was!

Comment: I can do it in one minute!